# Purpose of libpython3-stdlib

Tags: apt, python, python3

Ubuntu has the following `libpython3` packages

```
libpython3-all-dbg
libpython3-all-dev
libpython3-dbg
libpython3-dev
libpython3-stdlib
```

All the packages make sense, except for `libpython3-stdlib`. The content of the package are:

```
/usr/share/doc/libpython3-stdlib/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libpython3-stdlib/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libpython3-stdlib/copyright
```

Why are these files installed separately and not, say, part of `python3` package?

Answer (score 2):

Packaging *libpython3-stdlib* as a separate package allows programs that require *libpython3-stdlib* and its dependencies to easily install them all in a single command. Results of `apt-cache rdepends libpython3.6-stdlib` in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends libpython3.6-stdlib
libpython3.6-stdlib
Reverse Depends:
  libpython3.6
  idle-python3.6
  idle-python3.6
  python3.6
  python3-tk
  python3-tk
  python3-lib2to3
  python3-lib2to3
  python3-distutils
  python3-distutils
  libpython3.6-minimal
  libpython3.6-dev
  libpython3.6-dbg
  idle-python3.6
  libpython3-stdlib
  idle-python3.6
  python3-distutils
  python3.6
  python3-tk
  python3-tk
  python3-lib2to3
  python3-lib2to3
  python3-distutils
  libpython3-stdlib
  libpython3.6-minimal
  libpython3.6-dev
  libpython3.6-dbg
  libpython3.6
```

These packages all require libpython3.6-stdlib, which is itself a dependency of libpython3-stdlib, as a dependency.

From the results of `apt show libpython3-stdlib` in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Python, the high-level, interactive object oriented language, includes an extensive class   
library with lots of goodies for network programming, system administration, sounds   
and graphics.

This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default Python 3 version    
(currently v3.6).
```

Results of `apt-cache depends libpython3-stdlib` :

```
libpython3-stdlib
  Depends: libpython3.6-stdlib
```

From the results of `apt show libpython3.6-stdlib` in Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Python is a high-level, interactive, object-oriented language.  

Its 3.6 version includes an extensive class library with lots of goodies for   
network programming, system administration, sounds and graphics. 

This package contains Python 3.6's standard library.  
It is normally not used on its own, but as a dependency of python3.6.
```

Results of `apt-cache depends libpython3.6-stdlib` :

```
libpython3.6-stdlib
  Depends: libpython3.6-minimal
  Depends: mime-support
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libdb5.3
  Depends: libffi6
  Depends: liblzma5
  Depends: libmpdec2
  Depends: libncursesw5
  Depends: libreadline7
  Depends: libsqlite3-0
  Depends: libtinfo5
  Breaks: libmpdec2
  Breaks: libpython3.6-testsuite
  Breaks: python3-distutils
  Breaks: python3-numpy
  Breaks: python3-tk
  Replaces: libpython3.6-testsuite
  Replaces: python3-distutils
```

Answer (score 1):

`libpython3-stdlib` is some kind of dummy package depending on latest version of "Python3 standard library" (currently to `libpython3.6-stdlib`) which [contains](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/libpython3.6-stdlib/filelist):

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/LICENSE.txt
/usr/lib/python3.6/__phello__.foo.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/_compression.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/_dummy_thread.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/_markupbase.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/_osx_support.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/_pydecimal.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/_pyio.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/aifc.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/antigravity.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asynchat.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_futures.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_tasks.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/compat.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/constants.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/coroutines.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/futures.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/locks.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/log.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/proactor_events.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/protocols.py
...
```